# Is there a new version of Zend_Tool for ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-tool

if so, where can it be found?

is it going to have a new handle as to not conflict with zf1's tool?

```
zf2 create module admin
```

Zend_Tool documentation can be found here:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tool.usage.cli.html

Answer (score 2):

There is no Zend\Tool component implemented for Zend Framework yet. According to Matthew Weier O'Phinney (Project Lead Zend Framework):

> Zend\Console is being worked on for beta4, 
>   which lays the groundwork for new tooling; we may or may not have basic 
>   tooling available for beta4 (depends on when Console hits the master 
>   branch, basically).
>
> Right now, the preferred method for starting with the application is to 
>   use the ZendSkeletonApplication, along with ZendSkeletonModule, as these 
>   give the basic infrastructure you need to start development of an 
>   application and modules, respectively.

Source: http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Where-is-the-ZF-tool-in-ZF2-located-td4492524.html

Comment: It seems there is no tool right now, Zend\Console is used for letting your application run from console http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.console.introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

The new Zend Tool for Zend Framework 2 has been released recently and could be found on github: https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool